# Single Sign on implementation in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf

I have three jsf web application deployed on tomcat web server with SSL/TLS enabled. Now I want to build some kind of SSO authentication with particular roles. In tomcat conf/server.xml there is line:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
```

so I got idea that tomcat maybe have his own SSO implementation. Does anyone know where to find more information about this or some code examples?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"Does anyone know where to find more information about this or some code examples?"_ The internet? And please see #4 in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic In addition nothing in your question is plain java-se (jdk) related, nor JSF.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have found some stuff on the internet including tomcat reference, but not very useful. Anyway thanks.

Comment: [ask] also states to mention what you found after searchng and why it did not help. Suggestion: Don't develop something but look for broad (**not tomcat specific**) solutions. Many exist, just start searching for 'Single Sign On java frameworks' and throw some terms like sam open-id OAuth etc in there and you wil find lots of things

Answer (score 5):

After many hours of research I found solution, so I will post it here in case someone need SSO authentication in tomcat.
First of all open conf/server.xml file in tomcat installation directory and add following line:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    </Host>
```

By doing this, you have opened SSO valve. Next, you need to set up roles in tomcat. That is done by editing conf/tomcat-users.xml. Scroll to the bottom and add roles, something like this:

```
   <role rolename="CUSTOMER"/>
   <role rolename="ADMIN"/>
```

Now, if you want plain text authentication you can add users also by adding :

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="ADMIN"/>
<user username="customer" password="customer" roles="CUSTOMER"/>
```

or, if you have database you can set up connection with database server in conf/server.xml, I'm using MySQL:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
  driverName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?user=serverUsername&amp;password=serverPassword"
       userTable="usersTable" userNameCol="usernameColumnName" userCredCol="passwordColumnName"
   userRoleTable="roleTable" roleNameCol="roleColumnName"/>
```

**Note: You need to provide connection driver in tomcat lib directory.**
More info on: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm

Finally in your web app or apps, find web.xml and add security constrains:

```
<security-constraint>

 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>

 <user-data-constraint>
 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>  
 </user-data-constraint>

 <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

 </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>


<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Note: if you have custom Login page you can edit `<login-config>` tag and change to following:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Apache 9 Single Sign On Valve documentation is here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html.

Since you mentioned JSF (I'm not sure if you are using PrimeFaces & OmniFaces), maybe you are struggling also with log out/session time out. Specially if end user has open multiple windows/tabs and multiple applications (you mentioned you have three JSF apps), then

- OmniFaces [FacesExceptionFilter](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter) and
- OmniFaces [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler)

would be helpful for you. I can also recommend the best JSF book I've ever read

- [The Definitive Guide to JSF in Java EE 8](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484233863) written by BalusC (JSF expert, author of OmniFaces, etc.).